# My app is only availbale in US store, why?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, release

today my app finally releases on iTunes,and it's a free app but it is only available in US store. How can I change it to be available worldwide?

Comment: Did you choose the `US` country only when releasing your app?

Comment: You can change which stores your app is available in through iTunes Connect.

Comment: How long ago did it pass review? It can take hours for an app to propagate to all the stores.

Comment: @ Gray it is just about a 8hr which is available on iTunes

Comment: @RichardBrown Would you please tell where exactly I can change it thorough iTunesConnect ?

Comment: For anyone else getting here, I too had all stores checked/none checked and it only went up in the US - appears to be a bug somewhere with itunes connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the stores that your app appears in, 
Go to `iTunesConnect -> "Manage Your Applications"` Select your app and click the `"Rights and Pricing"` button. 
You can Check the stores here.

And if everything is fine here and Apple may need some time for updation.

thanks

Comment: I had selected all countries when I submitted it, I also check my iTunesConnect now, it is Worldwide!! does it takes some time to become in effect?? thanks in Advanced guys.

Comment: @siavashAlipour then i think surely Apple require some time for updation and may i know link of your app and Good Luck...!

Comment: sure, here it is: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ialgebra+/id615246482?ls=1&mt=8          Thanks,

Comment: Nice app and looking great app to you too i can see your app on India app store.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I have to wait.

Comment: No check this link. https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/ialgebra+/id615246482?mt=8

Comment: another thing, can I change the keywords for my app from iTunesConnect? Cause it is seems to me that it is not editable.

Comment: Yes,But you have to resubmit your app to change keywords unfortunately.

Comment: oh, it means waiting about a week again!!! that sucks.

Comment: Thanks guys, it is work now. It seems we should give iTunes a little time.

Comment: Can we change availability later to all countries later after releasing in US only first?